# R shiny - Huge blank space on top of the page

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shinyauthr

I have the following code that allow the user to :

1. Log in (username "a" and "password "a")
2. Display an app where the user will upload a CSV file and click on the "Generate Report" button. This action will Knit an Rmarkdown using the uploaded CSV file.
3. Once the report is ready, the user will download the report using the "Download report" button.

Everything works fine except the empty space that appears on the top of the page at the 2nd step. I am new to Shiny, so could someone please help me understand why there is that empty space and how I can get rid of it ?

[image]

Thank you very much !

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyauthr)

# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data
user_base <- tibble::tibble(
  user = c("a", "user2"),
  password = sapply(c("a", "pass2"), sodium::password_store),
  permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # logout button
  div(class = "pull-right", shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout")),
  
  # login section
  shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),
  
  # Sidebar to show user info after login
  uiOutput("sidebarpanel"),
  
  # Plot to show user info after login
  plotOutput("distPlot") ,
  
  
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Title"
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      tags$div(class = "sidebar-text",style = "text-align: center; font-style: italic;"),
      fileInput("csvFile1", "Load file")
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),  # Initialize shinyjs

      tags$br(),
      actionButton("knitButton", "Generate report"),
      downloadButton("downloadReport", "Download report", class = "btn-primary", disabled = TRUE)

    ) ) )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  credentials <- shinyauthr::loginServer(
    id = "login",
    data = user_base,
    user_col = user,
    pwd_col = password,
    sodium_hashed = TRUE,
    log_out = reactive(logout_init())
  )
  
  # Logout to hide
  logout_init <- shinyauthr::logoutServer(
    id = "logout",
    active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth)
  )
  
  
  observeEvent(input$knitButton, {
    # Check if two CSV files are uploaded and report options are selected
    if (
      !is.null(input$csvFile1) ) {
      # Show the loading screen
      shinyjs::show("loading")
      
      # Disable the knit button during knitting
      shinyjs::disable("knitButton")
      
      # Pathway to the RMarkdown code
      rmd_path <- "Rmarkdown.Rmd"
      
      knittedFile <- rmarkdown::render(
        rmd_path,
        output_file = "knitted_report.html",
        params = list(
          data1 = input$csvFile1$datapath ) )
      
      output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
        filename = paste0("Report.html") ,
        content = function(file) {
          file.copy(knittedFile, file)
        }
      )
      # Hide the loading screen
      shinyjs::hide("loading")
      
      # Show the "Ready" message
      shinyjs::show("ready")
      shinyjs::enable("downloadReport")
    }
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: (1) its recommended to either use fluidPage() or dashBoardPage() not both (2) its seems the graph even if it is not yet rendered, takes up space in the body

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. Which graph ? So, what is the difference between fluidPage() and dashBoardPage() ? Which one should be used in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

`fluidPage()` and `dashBoardPage()` are both HTML templates, by using both you are using an HTML template inside an HTML template, which of course you can do if you want to. So there is no 'this is the correct template for this app'. It all depends on your preferences, while `fluidPage()` is an almost 'empty' template, `dashBoardPage()` is already defined with some HTML/CSS elements, which - in case you use `fluidPage()` - you would have to code yourself.

With graph I meant `plotOutput("distPlot")`. You see, if you comment out this line, that blank space disappears.

See code example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyauthr)

# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data
user_base <- tibble::tibble(
  user = c("a", "user2"),
  password = sapply(c("a", "pass2"), sodium::password_store),
  permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two")
)


  
ui = dashboardPage(
    
     dashboardHeader(
      title = "Title"),
    
    dashboardSidebar(
      tags$div(class = "sidebar-text",style = "text-align: center; font-style: italic;"),
      fileInput("csvFile1", "Load file")),
    
    dashboardBody(
      
      # logout button
      div(class = "pull-right", shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout")),

      # login section
      shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),

      # # Sidebar to show user info after login
      # uiOutput("sidebarpanel"),
      # 
      # # Plot to show user info after login
      # plotOutput("distPlot") ,
      
      useShinyjs(),  # Initialize shinyjs
      
      tags$br(),
      actionButton("knitButton", "Generate report"),
      downloadButton("downloadReport", "Download report", class = "btn-primary", disabled = TRUE))
      
    ) 


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  credentials <- shinyauthr::loginServer(
    id = "login",
    data = user_base,
    user_col = user,
    pwd_col = password,
    sodium_hashed = TRUE,
    log_out = reactive(logout_init())
  )
  
  # Logout to hide
  logout_init <- shinyauthr::logoutServer(
    id = "logout",
    active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth)
  )
  
  
  observeEvent(input$knitButton, {
    # Check if two CSV files are uploaded and report options are selected
    if (
      !is.null(input$csvFile1) ) {
      # Show the loading screen
      shinyjs::show("loading")
      
      # Disable the knit button during knitting
      shinyjs::disable("knitButton")
      
      # Pathway to the RMarkdown code
      rmd_path <- "Rmarkdown.Rmd"
      
      knittedFile <- rmarkdown::render(
        rmd_path,
        output_file = "knitted_report.html",
        params = list(
          data1 = input$csvFile1$datapath ) )
      
      output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
        filename = paste0("Report.html") ,
        content = function(file) {
          file.copy(knittedFile, file)
        }
      )
      # Hide the loading screen
      shinyjs::hide("loading")
      
      # Show the "Ready" message
      shinyjs::show("ready")
      shinyjs::enable("downloadReport")
    }
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```